# How do I tell PyCharm user defined type of python dict in a function is okay?

Tags: python, pycharm

The code below runs fine, no warnings, with python 3.7.4.

```
from typing import Any, Dict, NewType

DocType = NewType('DocType', Dict[str, Any])

def print_doc(doc: DocType):
    for key, val in doc.items():
        print("key %s val %s" % (key, val))

print_doc({'a': 1, 'b': '2'})
```

However, in PyCharm (community 2019.2) I get a warning on the last line:

```
Expected type 'DocType', got 'Dict[str, Union[int, str]]' instead.
```

How can I inform PyCharm everything's okay?

The options PyCharm offers are to suppress the check for that line, and to turn off type checking altogether.  Neither seems great.

**EDIT**: If instead of defining my own DocType, I put `Dict[str, Any]` in the function prototype, the warning goes away.  I guess that's a workaround.

Comment: I think you want to use `TypeVar` instead of `NewType`.

Comment: Sadly, nope. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#newtype. Also, trying TypeVar there doesn't work.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I just made a mistake. You can directly use `DocType = Dict[str, Any]` as you don't need `TypeVar`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NewType` marks your `DocType` as a subtype of `dict`, and since you are passing a dictionary (which is a supertype of your `DocType`), PyCharm correctly marks it as an eror.

You can either instantiate the variable as a `DocType`:

```
from typing import Any, Dict, NewType

DocType = NewType('DocType', Dict[str, Any])

def print_doc(doc: DocType) -> None:
    for key, val in doc.items():
        print("key %s val %s" % (key, val))


print_doc(DocType({'a': 1, 'b': '2'}))
```

or create a type alias

```
from typing import Any, Dict, NewType

DocType = Dict[str, Any]

def print_doc(doc: DocType) -> None:
    for key, val in doc.items():
        print("key %s val %s" % (key, val))


print_doc({'a': 1, 'b': '2'})
```